# Set locale to sv_SE on debian

Tags: postgresql, debian

Using Postgres 9.1 on Debian 7

Postgresql gives an error message when creating database setting "LC_COLLATE = 'sv_SE.UTF-8'"

As I understand now, the language support is from the underlying Debian and i cannot set the correct language there.

```
> locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

and this does not help:

```
> locale-gen sv_SE.UTF-8
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
Generation complete.
```

Resulting in:

```
> locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

Any clue what to do? The aim is to get Postgresql correct sort order when creating database.

I found the solution by chance:

1. Uncomment the # sv_SE.UTF-8 in etc/locale.gen by deleting #
2. Run sudo locale-gen
3. Restart server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`locale-gen` on **Debian** doesn't expect any argument, so presumably the `sv_SE.UTF-8` passed to it is ignored. From its [manpage](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=locale-gen&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%207.0%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en):

> SYNOPSIS
>          locale-gen
>          ....
>          locale-gen is a program that reads the file /etc/locale.gen and invokes
>          localedef for the chosen localisation profiles.  Run  locale-gen  after
>          you have modified the /etc/locale.gen file.

This differs from **Ubuntu** ([manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/locale-gen.8.html)) which for some reason has a very different synopsis and behavior:

```
 locale-gen [options] [locale] [language] ...
```

The problem in the question stems from applying to Debian a method to generate locales that works only with Ubuntu.

The step #3 in your edit may also be emphasized: the postgres server must be restarted for it to recognize a new locale, otherwise it will complain it doesn't exist.